# How can I effectively use a struct definition including operators from another source file?

Tags: c++, struct, namespaces, operators

I have a project which consists of several submodules. As I have some structs like e.g. Point or Rectangle, I wanted to have a separate header file where those data structures and their operators are defined. This is then included by other source files. I have

#### structures.hpp

```
namespace datastructures {
    struct Rectangle {
         int width;
         int height;
    };


bool operator<=(const Rectangle& lhs, const Rectangle& rhs){
    return lhs.width <= rhs.width;
} 
}// end namespace
```

#### Algorithm.hpp

I have another file Algorithm.hpp which looks similar to:

```
#include "structures.hpp"
class Algorithm {
public:
     typedef datastructures::Rectangle Rectangle;
     void func1(int median);
private:
     std::vector<Rectangle> rectangles_;
}
```

This compiles all just fine. But using the operator does not seem to work at all.

#### Algorithm.cpp

```
void Algorithm::func1(int median){
     std::nth_element(rectangles_.begin(), 
     rectangles_.begin() + median, rectangles_.end(), datastructures::operator<=);
}
```

This gives compiler errors for the templates, the most meaningful is

```
no matching function for call to 
‘nth_element(std::vector<datastructures::Rectangle>::iterator&, 
std::vector<datastructures::Rectangle>::iterator&, 
std::vector<datastructures::Rectangle>::iterator&, 
<unresolved overloaded function type>)’
```

Why doesn't it know the `operator<=` from my datastructures header file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is due to:

```
unresolved overloaded function type
```

There must multiple operator matching the signature.
You could use something like `boost::function` or a function pointer to select a particular overload or use a comparator functor http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/less_equal

eg:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>

namespace datastructures {

  struct Foo;

  struct Rectangle {
    int width;
    int height;
  };

  bool operator<=(const Rectangle& lhs, const Rectangle& rhs){
    return lhs.width <= rhs.width;
  } // end namespace                                                                                                                                                                                                

  bool operator<=(const Foo&, const Foo&);

}

class Algorithm {
public:
  typedef datastructures::Rectangle Rectangle;
  void func1(int median);
private:
  std::vector<Rectangle> rectangles_;
};

// Algorithm.hpp                                                                                                                                                                                                    
void Algorithm::func1(int median){
  // this fails
  std::nth_element(rectangles_.begin(),
                   rectangles_.begin() + median, rectangles_.end(), datastructures::operator<=);
  // this works
  std::nth_element(rectangles_.begin(),
                   rectangles_.begin() + median, rectangles_.end(), std::less_equal<Rectangle>());

}
```

You also will have to declare your compare function as `inline` otherwise you'll get multiple definitions in link step.

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you!! The less_equal solution worked!!

Comment: don't forget to upvote useful answers and accept the correct one ;-)

Comment: I upvoted, but my reputation score is too low... Sorry about that! But at least I can accept the answer!

Answer (score 0):

Changing:

```
private:
   std::vector<Rectangle> rectangles_;
```

to this:

```
private:
   std::vector<datastructures::Rectangle> rectangles_;
```

and also adding an extra closing brace in the `structures.hpp` file (for the namespace), allows me compile the code fine. Have you deliberately left out the closing brace for the namespace in `structures.hpp`?

Comment: No, sorry, the bracket got lost while copying and editing my code.

Comment: But as I have nested namespaces, not like my simplified example from above, I would appreciate using the shortened typedef Rectangle.